# Gazebo is not publishing clock

Tags: ros, gazebo, clock

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My Gazebo is not publishing the clock anymore. I don't know what I did wrong. A few days ago it worked, but not anymore.

"use_sim_time" is set to true (`rosparam get use_sim_time` returns true)
The time in the simulator is running.

I used the sasc version of Gazebo (Gazebo 8.0), but reverting to 7.5 doesn't change it.

Between the last time it worked and the first time I noticed it doesn't work anymore, I installed CUDA 8 and compiled OpenCV 3.1 from source. But I also reverted back to CUDA 7.5 and the default opencv of my system which doesn't make it work.

It seems to me that on no other topics something is published either. But if I manually publish something (i.e. `rostopic pub /test std_msgs/String "test" -r 5`) I can display the content via rostopic echo.

Any clues of what might be wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255683/gazebo-is-not-publishing-clock/) by [WLemkens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4068/wlemkens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2017-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If nothing is publishing, check firewalls and whether you have a `ROS_IP`, `ROS_HOSTNAME` or `ROS_MASTER_URI` setting in your `.bashrc` that points to wrong IP addresses.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WLemkens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4068/wlemkens/) on 2017-02-27**:
Yes thank you! It was pointing to 127.0.0.1 instead of my real ip-address.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-27**:
What was pointing to `127.0.0.1`? In any case, that should probably also work.

**Comment by [WLemkens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4068/wlemkens/) on 2017-02-27**:
ROS_IP and ROS_MASTER_URI were pointing to 127.0.0.1. After changing it to use the ip of my network card the messages were working again.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-27**:
If you are not trying to distribute your ROS application across multiple networked hosts, the setting all of those is probably not necessary. Not setting them will allow ROS to detect proper values for them automatically.